# How to rewrite these 3 methods to be reusable?

Tags: java, arraylist, redundancy

I'm making a tankgame. In my `PlayPanel` class I wrote this code, as you can see it is mostly the same but it's used for 3 different `ArrayList`s.

I would really like to know how to write this method once only in order to reuse it for all the `ArrayList`s because it seems so untidy.

```
//obstacles
for (int i = 0 ; i<obstacles.size() ; i++) {
    if (obstacles.get(i).dood)
        obstacles.remove(i);
}
//bullets
for (int i = 0; i< bullets.size(); i++) {
    bullets.get(i).redraw();
    //de positie van elke kogel wordt geupdate.
    if(bullets.get(i).OutOfScreen()) {
        bullets.remove(i);//uit scherm -> verwijdert en verplaatst
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i< enemyBullets.size(); i++) {
    enemyBullets.get(i).redraw();
    if(enemyBullets.get(i).OutOfScreen()) {
        enemyBullets.remove(i);
    }
}
```

I thought about writing this, but it doesn't seem right:

```
public void remove(ArrayList object) {
    for (int i = 0; i< object.size(); i++) {
        object.get(i).redraw();
        if(object.get(i).OutOfScreen()) {
            object.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I don't really know how to call this method to use it for one of the `ArrayList`s.

Comment: you have 3 arrayLists for different goals, so I think one of them has to be taken care of individually. could you please explain **"i don't really know how to call this method to use it for one of the ArrayLists."**  better? your post is kind of unclear what you are asking

Comment: The three loops are not really the same. The first seems to be using a boolean flag `dood`. The other 2 look the same and your method seems right. What problem are you getting exactly?

Comment: @KickButtowski i don't know how to make java perform the last method i wrote for the ArrayLists `enemyBullet `and `bullets` and where in my code i have to write the `remove` method

Comment: @Sophia do not you think you should follow whatever specification that you have? I do not think anyone can tell u where you should use the logic except you?

Comment: What are types of `enemybullets` , `bullets` and `obstacles` lists? If they of same type or inherited from common type then method like `remove` can work.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Java 8, you can filter the list with by passing a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html).

```
public class Helper {
    //removePredicate can be any function that returns a boolean that will help
    //to filter the data
    static <T> void remove(List<T> list, Predicate<? super T> removePredicate) {
        List<T> filteredList = list.stream()
            .filter(removePredicate)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(filteredList);
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how to use method above for `List<Bullet>`:

```
//sample implementation for Bullet class
class Bullet {
    int value;
    public Bullet(int value) { this.value = value; }
    public boolean outOfScreen() {
        return value > 10;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return String.format("Bullet: {%d}", value);
    }
}

//somewhere you need to execute this code...
//initialize your List
List<Bullet> bulletList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    new Bullet(15), new Bullet(1), new Bullet(20), new Bullet(6)));
//show the contents of the list
System.out.println(bulletList);
//remove the elements by using whatever you want/need
//see how you can pass any way to filter the elements of the list
Helper.remove(bulletList, b -> !b.outOfScreen());
//show the contents of the list again to show how it was filtered
System.out.println(bulletList);
```

The benefit of using this approach is that you don't need class inheritance or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The second and third loop can be combined in a single piece of code as shown as follows.

1. You have a parent class (Abstract or Interface) called ParentBullets.
2. Bullets and EnemyBullets are child classes of ParentBullets class.

Now via Polymorphism you can do the following

```
public void loop(List<? extends ParentBullets> bullets){
for (int i = 0; i< bullets.size(); i++) {
    bullets.get(i).redraw();
    //de positie van elke kogel wordt geupdate.
    if(bullets.get(i).OutOfScreen()) {
        bullets.remove(i);//uit scherm -> verwijdert en verplaatst
    }
}
}
```

Now you can have bullets and enemybullets as a collection is an ArrayList and you can call the above method like:

loop(bullets);
or 
loop(enemyBullets);

Answer (score -1):

Your method `remove` won't work, since you are giving as an argument an `ArrayList` of `Object`s. They don't have methods `redraw` and `OutOfScreen`. What you could do is define an interface, say `GameObject`, containing these methods, and make `Bullet` implement it.
Change signature of `remove` to

```
public void remove(ArrayList<? extends GameObject> object) {
    //rest as before
}
```

Then you can call for example `remove(bullets)` or `remove(enemyBullets)`.

Comment: You cannot add or remove elements using this kind of generics.

Comment: Oops, right. Still, we can have `public void remove(ArrayList<GameObject> object)`, only then `bullets` must  be an instance of `ArrayList<GameObject>` instead of `AraryList<Bullet>`.