# How to compare and reorder an ArrayList of objects based on a list of another objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 arraylists, one of type String and the other is a custom class Person.

```
List names = new ArrayList<String>(); 
List people = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Both lists are populated like so:

```
names.add("bob");
names.add("joe");
names.add("tom");
people.add(new Person("joe")); //Assuming Person has a name property
people.add(new Person("tom"));
people.add(new Person("bob"));
```

Notice that the same names have been used in both lists, but added in different order. How can I sort the `people` arraylist in the same order as the `names`?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/ may be a good read. You need either a Comparator or make Person Comparable.

Comment: Is `names` guaranteed to be alphabetical?

Comment: you need insertion order or alphabetical?

Comment: Do you mean "sort" or simply "reorder"? As in, "reorder the `people` array to match the order in the `names`" array?

Comment: `names` is not guaranteed alphabetical.

Comment: Yes I probably should have said reorder.

Comment: Why would you need two lists in this instance?

Comment: This was a simple example, it's not the actual code. I just want to understand if there is an easy way to reorder the list.

Comment: You've actually brought up a more complicated problem than it seems on first glance. You're wanting the order of objects in one list to remain consistent with the order of a dissimilar object in a different list. You're going to have to design some sort of commonality between them that gives you a programmatic basis to marry that relationship beyond just Comparable, which doesn't really do what you want. Perhaps a derived class that returns a reference to the LIst<String> from your List<Person>?

Comment: Is it possible that any of the people might have the same name?  If so, it looks like you don't have enough information to but the people into the correct (re-ordered) sequence - e.g. which "joe" (string list) is which `person.getName().equals("joe")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange requirement, but you can do it by using a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Person> personMap = new HashMap<>();
//Assuming people is declared rightfully as List<Person> rather than just List
for (Person people : people) {
    personMap.put(person.getName(), person);
}
List<Person> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (String name : names) {
    if (personMap.containsKey(name)) {
        results.add(personMap.get(name));
    }
}
//in case you need to work with people only
people.clear();
people.addAll(results);
```

Comment: Any reason for using a separate `results` list? Why not simply clear `people` and add directly to that when iterating through `names`?

Comment: @TedHopp well, I was thinking to use a Java 8 solution as proposed here [in this other answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30268848/1065197) and used that way.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `names` array can apparently be in an arbitrary order, the concept of "sorting" isn't very applicable. The most direct approach, I think, is to rebuild the `people` array from the given `names` array by using a map. Something like this might work:

```
void reoderPeople(ArrayList<Person> people, ArrayList<String> names) {
    // first build the map
    Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Person p : people) {
        map.add(p.getName(), p);
    }
    // now re-create the people array
    people.clear();
    for (String name : names) {
        people.add(map.get(name));
    }
}
```

This assumes that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the elements of `names` and `people` based on the name. If that's not a correct assumption, then this approach would have to be modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a comparator for sorting people which uses ordering of names list. (Untested code below)

```
Collections.sort(people, new Comparator<Person>(){
  public int comapre(Person a, Person b) {
    Integer indexA = names.indexOf(a.getName());
    Integer indexB = names.indexOf(b.getName());
    return indexA.compareTo(indexB);
  }
});
```

Comment: Finally, a comparison-based approach that will will work (provided one changes `public int comapre` to `public int compare`). But this seems like a strikingly inefficient compared to building a map.